# Is it true that yichud is less of an issue with Nachrim since its not relevant to do an issur with them?

Tags: gentiles, sexuality, yichud-seclusion

I remember learning that yichud could be potentially more serious when a nachri is involved since they are known to be prutzim. However, recently I saw something (wish i could remember where) about a nachri being more kal becuase its not relevant.

Comment: Well at the very least it's only yichud, while with a Jew you have yichud + lifnei iver

Comment: Yichud with a non-Jew was prohibited by decree of the students of Beis Hillel and Beis Shammai (*'Avoda Zara* 36b, "ואתו תלמידי בית שמאי ובית הלל גזור אפי' אייחוד דעובדת כוכבים"; Rambam, *Hil. Issurei Bi'ah* 22:3).

Comment: @Fred please may I request you turn this into an answer rather than a comment as it would be an asset to Mi Yodeya